# Why is the Mobius transform called a linear transform?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

It has the form

$$ z \rightarrow w = \frac{a z +b}{cz +d } . $$

This is apparently not a linear function. A linear function should be in the form of

$$ w = a z +b ,$$

right?

ps: I am reading the book by Ahlfors.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055559/why-mobius-transformation-is-isomorphic-to-projective-linear-group.

Answer (score 2):

You're right: Ahlfors calls it a linear transformation.

The current term is now [linear *fractional* transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation).