# What's the point of studying isomorphisms?

Tags: group-isomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I'm trying to learn about groups/rings and the concept of isomorphisms appears everywhere. I understand that an isomorphism between groups/rings shows that arithmetic in both structures is essentially the same, but I don't understand how this can be applied to deduce anything about them. If someone could give an example or explain how isomorphisms can be used to answer a question I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: An example maybe is that the Mobius transformation is isomorphic to the projective linear group as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055559/why-möbius-transformation-is-isomorphic-to-projective-linear-group. This reduces asking about a geometric transformation to something that can be done with complex matrices, which is more concrete.